# Check if cookie is existing returns all array

Tags: laravel, cookies

I am trying to check if cookie is stored or not. If not existing, it returns all the stored cookies in an application. It's supposed to be `null`, right?

```
$cookie = $request->cookie(config('app.name' .'_VERIFIED'));
dump($cookie);
```

This code above, if cookie is not existing, returns all stored cookies. If existing, then it will return the value. I want a `null` value if not existing.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the default behavior of laravel. But if the first parameter of `$request->cookie()` is null it will return all cookie values. You have to make sure that you always get a value from `config('app.name' .'_VERIFIED')`

Answer (score 1):

The way method `$request->cookie` work is, when you past a key to the `cookie` function, It will call the `cookie` method which is define in [`Illuminate\Http\Concerns`](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/3ecf66897cc854ce42acecd54aff310f0a2e2aca/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L298) Concern which call the `retrieveItem` method which take the `cookies` is define like this

```
 protected function retrieveItem($source, $key, $default){}
```

the `$source` parameter will set to **cookies** and the `$key` will be set to the key you past, if the key is set to null, it will return all content of the cookie object. if `$key` is not null it will call the method `get` on the `cookies` source which is of type `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag` like define in the [\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/b5f0424be5df8b9d8f5ea69d97ffc6cce2812174/Request.php#L109) which is the class that `Illuminate\Http\Request` class extends. Which return the content of key depending of it value.